# How to redirect URL in .htaccess with condition?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have domain with url `https://reg.bmi.id`. I'd like to make any user that type anything after the url is redirected to `https://reg.bmi.id`.

Example:

- `https://reg.bmi.id/admin` will be redirected in to `https://reg.bmi.id`
- `https://reg.bmi.id/asidjadhqowidhqohuqw` will be redirected in to `https://reg.bmi.id`
- `https://reg.bmi.id/asdjqoq/qdoqwun/qowidopq` will be redirected in to `https://reg.bmi.id`
- `https://reg.bmi.id/contact/contact.php` will be redirected in to `https://reg.bmi.id`

In exception, if the user precisely type `https://reg.bmi.id/reg_pilot` then it will not be redirected. It open the page of `/reg_pilot`

This is my current .htaccess which is located in root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^reg\.bmi\.id$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.reg\.bmi\.id$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/reg\.bmi\.id\/" [R=301,L]
```

`reg/pilot` is a reference to any other rsources on this domain. `/contact/contact.php` is not exist. Anything typed except `/reg_pilot` after the domain is should be redirected

I have little to no  experience dealing about .htaccess any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
##Setting rewrite base here.
RewriteBase /

##Checking for non https requests and applying https to it with/without www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?reg\.bmi\.id$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://reg.bmi.id/ [R=301,L]

##Stopping/forbidding direct access of index.php here.
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

##Any non existing directory/file is served by php file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !reg_pilot [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://reg.bmi.id/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi @RavindeSingh13, it's working nice. But, the url changed into `https://register.bigi.id/index.php` after user type something after the domain. how to remove the index.php? I'd like to mak the url `https://register.bigi.id/`

Comment: @Shota, Good to hear that its working. Ideally rules are NOT redirecting to index.php in browser, I tested them in my localhost and they worked fine. Could you please do let me know if you have any other Rules in your file? Apart from these rules.

Comment: No, I have not othe rule beside that  in .htaccess

Comment: @Shota, oh ok, I had mentioned url `https://reg.bmi.id/` in rules but in your previous comments you mentioned `https://register.bigi.id/` if they are different then  please make sure you mention your actual URL in rule file please.

Comment: Oh sorry it's a typo

Comment: @Shota, When I hit a url like `http://loalhost:80/test/blabla` it redirects to `http://localhost:80/`

Comment: Good answer Ravinder Singh.!

Comment: I upload it in a hosting. Should I change something in my hosting?

Comment: @Shota, not sure, without seeing it its very difficult for anyone. But these rules are well working on Local system, if you have htaccess in your localhost(windows/Linux) you could test it by yourself too. Please do let me know in case you have any queries here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 if I delete this part `RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L]`, the index.php is gone but the `https://reg.bmi.id/reg_pilot` show 404 not found. Assume in your environment you have the `index.php` what should I change in this part?

Comment: @Shota, ok, how about changing last rule to `RewriteRule ^ /index.php [NC,L]` once? Let me know how it goes. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: After I clear my browser cache, my website loads without its css

Comment: @Shota, oh ok, You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: I compare the base_url from the old .htaccess and the new one. the result is the path is same. so, why the new .htaccess not load my css?

Comment: @Shota, you need to provide absolute paths in href tag like I mentioned above else it will be a problem, let me know if you have any queries on same.

Comment: I've add it but still no luck. could you show me where to put it in your answer?

Comment: @Shota, ok, could you please do let me know which link you are hitting and what's exactly happening?

Comment: A side note: `^(?:www\.)reg\.bmi\.id$` will only match "www.reg.bmi.id" but _not_ "reg.bmi.id" ...

Comment: @arkascha, sure, I have edited that now to make it optional.